# Couldn't understand a step in solving Homogenous Linear Recurrence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I was reading a Wiki on Brilliant.org regarding [linear recurrence relations](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/#linear-recurrence-relations-with-repeated-roots). They have mentioned that, "***note that if two geometric series satisfy a recurrence, the sum of them also satisfies the recurrence***".

And I am stuck there! How do can we prove the above statement formally? In addition to this how do we prove that $u_{n} = c_{1}u_{n-1}+...+c_{k}u_{n-k} \implies a_{n} = \alpha_{1}r_{1}^{n}+\alpha_{2}r_{2}^{n}$ .

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You mean like if $a_n=ra_{n-1}$ and $b_n=rb_{n-1}$ then $a_n+b_n=r(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})$?

Comment: While solving recurrence relations we assume a solution of the form $a_{n} = \alpha_{1}r_{1}^{n}+\alpha_{2}r_{2}^{n}$. I was confused how does this form come. Like why is it the way it is? Why don't we assume a solution of the form $a_{n} = \alpha_{1}r_{1}^{n}*\alpha_{2}r_{2}^{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s just a matter of checking the algebra. Suppose that the recurrence is

$$x_n=c_1x_{n-1}+c_2x_{n-2}+\ldots+c_kx_{n-k}\;,\tag{1}$$

and that $x_n=ar^n$ and $x_n=bs^n$ both satisfy it, meaning that

$$ar^n=c_1ar^{n-1}+c_2ar^{n-2}+\ldots+c_kar^{n-k}$$

and

$$bs^n=c_1bs^{n-1}+c_2bs^{n-2}+\ldots+c_kbs^{n-k}\;.$$

Let $u_n=ar^n+bs^n$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
u_n&=ar^n+bs^n\\
&=(c_1ar^{n-1}+c_2ar^{n-2}+\ldots+c_kar^{n-k})+\\
&\quad+(c_1bs^{n-1}+c_2bs^{n-2}+\ldots+c_kbs^{n-k})\\
&=c_1(ar^{n-1}+bs^{n-1})+c_2(ar^{n-2}+bs^{n-2})+\ldots+c_k(ar^{n-k}+bs^{n-k})\\
&=c_1u_{n-1}+c_2u_{n-2}+\ldots+c_ku_{n-k}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so the sequence $\langle u_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle ar^n+bs^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, the sum of the two geometric sequences, also satisfies the recurrence $(1)$.

Comment: I think the proof which are telling implies if $u_{n} = ar^{n}+br^{n}$ then $u_{n} = c_{1}u_{n-1}+...+c_{k}u_{n-k}$. I need a proof of the other way around.

Comment: @Puneet: Yes, that is what I’m proving; that is what the boldface statement in your question says. If that’s not what you wanted, you’ll need to revise the question.

Comment: You are right sir. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Puneet: The implication that you’ve added isn’t necessarily true: if $k=2$ the solution may be the sum of just two geometric solutions, but even then it’s not guaranteed: it may be of the form $ar^n+bnr^n$, the sum of a geometric solution and one that isn’t purely geometric. And if $k>2$, the general solution will be the sum of $k$ solutions.

Comment: Wait! I think I got it! I don't know why I was confused again. Thank you very much for the help. I just accepted you answer.

Comment: @Puneet: We don’t always assume a solution of the form $a_n=\alpha_1r_1^n+\alpha_2r_2^n$: we do that only when $k=2$ and the characteristic equation $r^2=c_1r+c_2$ has distinct roots. (I’m afraid that I can’t actually check your link, since I’m not a member.)

Comment: @Puneet: Excellent! I’m glad that you got it.